# Find next word after the matching keyword in a list of strings using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, lambda

I have a list of strings and I want to extract the next word after a specific keyword in each string.

When I am using the lambda function to iterate over the list, I am getting the whole strings instead of just the next word after the keyword:

```
import re
s = ["The job ABS is scheduled by Bob.", "The job BFG is scheduled by Alice."]
user = filter(lambda i:re.search('(?<=The job )(\w+)',i),s)
print(*user)

output: The job ABS is scheduled by Bob. The job BFG is scheduled by Alice.
```

but, when I am trying the same code for a single string, it is giving the correct output:

```
import re
s = "The job ABS is scheduled by Bob."
user = re.search('(?<=The job )(\w+)',s)
print(user.group())

output: ABS
```

How can I get output like (ABS, BFG) from the first code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
s = ["The job ABS is scheduled by Bob.", "The job BFG is scheduled by Alice."]
rx = re.compile(r'(?<=The job )\w+')
user = tuple(map(lambda x: x.group() or "", map(rx.search, s)))
print(user)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MbcwhN).

Alternatively, if there can be any amount of whitespace, use

```
rx = re.compile(r'The\s+job\s+(\w+)')
user = tuple(map(lambda x: x.group(1) or "", map(rx.search, s)))
```

Output:

```
('ABS', 'BFG')
```

Here, the `map(rx.search, s)` returns an iterator to the match data objects or `None`s, and the outer `map(lambda x: x.group(...) or "", ...)` gets the value of the group (either the whole match with `.group()` or Group 1  value with `.group(1)`), or returns an empty string if there was no match.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this:

```sh
import re

arr = ["The job ABS is scheduled by Bob.", "The job BFG is scheduled by Alice."]
user = [re.findall('(?<=The job )\w+', s) for s in arr]
print (user)
print (tuple(user))
```

**Output:**

```
[['ABS'], ['BFG']]
(['ABS'], ['BFG'])
```

Comment: `findall` is not necessary if a single match is required.

Comment: It is good enough if it simplifies code that much